# Make Instagram swipeable post. Means take one image and crop it into 3 or 4 equal parts

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

**I want to make an android app that will make an Instagram swipeable post.**

Means take one image and crop it into 3 or 4 equal parts.

[See this Image of result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UA7P.jpg)

**check this app** to get idea what I want

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.muffin.instapanorama

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling Thanks. Improved it. I just need a piece of code that divides the image into the required number of grid size